# It is possible to use OWIN Nancy with Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, nancy, owin

I define Nancy class like this:

```
public class DefNancy : NancyModule
{
    public DefNancy() : base("/nancy") {
        Get["/"] = _ => {
            var model = new { title = "Hello world" };
            return View["home", model];
        };
    }
}
```

And in OWIN Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);

        config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("def","api/{Controller}");
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); 
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

But now my *.aspx and another pages return 404 Error.

Comment: If you're using Nancy, why do you have WebAPI in there?

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
app.UseNancy(options =>
    options.PerformPassThrough = context =>
        context.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

Comment: Thank you - This helped me get MiniProfiler working :-)